# Removing any videos from a HTML fragment

Tags: html, youtube, perl, video-embedding

I have a (possibly not conforming to any standards) HTML fragment with embedded video. The problem is to remove the subfragment(s) with the video.

It is expected that the video follows this format:

`<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX&amp;feature=youtu.be"><iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX?feature=oembed" tabindex="-1" width=" 480"></iframe></div>`

I am entirely unsure whether all data follows this scheme.

I think any `div` or `p` containing only the video should be removed, too.

Please help to write Perl code to remove video. Which Perl module do you recommend to use for parsing?

Comment: Try using Mojo::DOM

Comment: You say you are unsure whether all data follows this scheme, but, tbh, unless you know of something (or things) that specifically identifies the tags you want to remove, and never appears in tags you want to keep, then you are going to struggle.

Comment: @TomMelly Hm, I may just remove all iframes

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: @DaveCross My main problem was choosing a Perl module to accomplish this task. Because I didn't know which module to use, I didn't write any code yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub RemoveVideo {
  my ($str) = @_;

  my $attrRe = qr/\s*(?<name>\b\S+\b)\s*=\s*(?<value>"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^"'<>\s]+)\s*/;
  my $iframeRe = qr{<iframe\b($attrRe)*>\s*</iframe\s*>|<iframe\b($attrRe)*\s*/>}i;
  my $divRe = qr{<div\b($attrRe)*>\s*$iframeRe\s*</div\s*>\s*}i;
  my $pRe = qr{<p\b($attrRe)*>\s*$iframeRe\s*</p\s*>\s*}i;
  $str =~ s/$divRe//gms;
  $str =~ s/$pRe//gms;
  $str =~ s/$iframeRe//gms; # "голый" iframe (не внутри дива)

  return $str;
}
my $Test = <<EOF;
XXX
<IFRAME allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX?feature=oembed" tabindex="-1" width=" 480"></iframe>
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX&amp;feature=youtu.be"><iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX?feature=oembed" tabindex="-1" width=" 480"></iframe></div>
<p data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX&amp;feature=youtu.be"><iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX?feature=oembed" tabindex="-1" width=" 480"></iframe></p>
YYY
EOF

print RemoveVideo($Test);
```